# Proving a field is algebraically closed with algebraic geometry

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory

There's a [fun proof](https://mathoverflow.net/a/39380/4054) of the fundamental theorem of algebra that goes like this:

Let $\mathbb{C}_n[X]$ be the complex vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$ in a variable $X$ and consider the holomorphic map
$$
f : \prod_{j=1}^n \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}_1[X]) \to \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{C}_n[X]),
\quad
([p_1], \ldots, [p_n]) \mapsto [p_1 \cdots p_n]
$$
between two compact complex manifolds. By inspection in well-chosen charts, $df$ is injective on a dense set and thus surjective as well because the tangent bundles have the same dimension. The map $f$ is therefore regular there, and its fiber at such a point has $|S_n| = n!$ points, so $f$ is finite. Finally, a finite holomorphic map between compact complex manifolds of the same dimension is surjective, either by general differential topology facts about finite maps and the orientability of complex manifolds, or by Grauert and Remmert's open mapping theorem and standard topological arguments involving compactness and Hausdorff spaces. Therefore any polynomial of degree $n$ splits into linear factors, so $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed.

There are of course algebraicially closed fields $k$ that are not the complex numbers.

**Question:** Suppose we do the same thing but over an arbitrary field $k$. Then we have a finite morphism between algebraic varieties. Is there a property of $k$ (other than "$k$ is algebraically closed") that lets us conclude that the algebraic morphism $f$ is surjective?

I don't know enough algebraic geometry (or algebra, honestly) to say much about what happens in the general case. When $k = \mathbb{R}$ it's easy to prove directly that this map isn't surjective for $n = 2$ by considering a kind of projectivized version of the discriminant of a polynomial that takes values in $\{\text{positive}, 0, \text{negative}\}$ and noting that the image of $f$ never takes a negative value. That argument doesn't work for (for example) a finite field, which is also not algebraically closed.

Comment: After thinking about this a little more I wonder if such a statement is "a finite morphism between things (schemes? varieties?) of the same dimension is surjective" and the question boils down to that being equivalent to the field being algebraically closed?

Comment: I think you are missing a subtelty here: being surjective is not enough, you need the map on $k$-points to be surjective. The squaring map $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}\to\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$ is surjective but evidently the induced map on $k$-points $(k^\times)\to (k^\times)$ is not surjective. Implicitly the complex geometry proof is using the fact that the analytification of a variety over $\mathbb{C}$ has the $\mathbb{C}$-points of that variety as its point set.